# How to trigger ngAnimate class sequence when using element.addClass inside directive

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

Inside of a directive I'm adding various classes on an element based on user interaction.

How can I get the `ngAnimate` class sequence (e.g. `my-class-add` -> `my-class-add-active`) when using `element.addClass` in place of `ngClass` directive?

I want to use CSS transitions, not JS animations.

Thanks.

Comment: can't you use `ng-class` and let scope model handle the changes? Why is `addClass` needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the class via the animate service (angularjs 1.2) like

```
module.directive('directive', function ($animate) {
    return {
        restrict:"A",
        link: function($scope,$element) {
            $element.on("click", function() {
                $animate.addClass($element,"my-animation");
            });        
        };
    }
});
```

[Doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate.%24animate)

Comment: Was looking at the code for `ngClass` and it does use `$animate.addClass` behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks, it's what I was looking for. I edited your answer to invert parameter order, element is first, then the class name.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you'd delegate that to another directive which is tied in with ngAnimate (i.e. ng-show, ng-if, ng-repeat .etc.)

You can set a scope property and let another directive handle the animation classes.

Comment: Hi. I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean.